# Добавления элемента с ключем в массив php

Tags: php, массивы

возник такой вопрос.

Как добавить элемент с ключом в массив?

Вот к примеру.

Массив:

```
$arr = [
 'one' => 1,
 'two' => 2
];
```

И нужно добавить элемент в конец массива. Документация выдает нам [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php).

Но, выполняя код:

```
 array_push($arr,3);
```

То на выходе выходит:

```
 array(3) {
   ["one"]=>int(1)
   ["two"]=>int(2)
   [0] => int(3)
 }
```

И как, к примеру, добавить элемент 3 с ключом "three"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень просто. `$arr['three'] = 3;`

Comment: Воу. Точно. Спасибо. )